# VBA code changes from text into numeric value of a range, however no tall the columns?

Tags: excel, vba

i wrote a code in VBA to change values in a range from text into general (number). it works fine, however there is one issue. when i checked all the column values, only the string with an integer value ("2345") is changed to integer (2345) but the strings with float values ("123.456") didn't change at all, the type changed into General but the value stay the same.

here is the vba code

```
If (ws.Name = "TB") Then
    shTB.Activate
    [A:A].Select
    With Selection
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
```

results as the table below, still the float values didn't change at all. as you can see only row 119 changed into Number or integer.Any suggestion or help is appreciated highly!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if that "." stands for thousands separator then just remove it

```
With shTB.Range("A:A")
    .Replace what:=".", replacement:=vbNullString
    .NumberFormat = "General"
End With
```

BTW, as you see you don't need to select anything: just act on its direct reference

Comment: I mean to replace dots with nullstring (i.e. delete them) as per your example "_""123.456""_

Answer (score 1):

It is clear from your results that there is a mis-match between the text format of your data and your Locale settings.

You data appears to have come from a source in which the comma is the decimal separator rather than the period.  Try:

```
Sub dural()
    With Range("A:A")
            .NumberFormat = "General"
            .Replace ",", "."
            .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```